# How to reload Model methods on CFWheels?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have a model like this:

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
<cffunction name="init">

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="config">
   ...
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getLogsEncuestas">
    <cfreturn ...>
</cffunction>
```

I am creating the getLogsEncuestas method, but every time I made a change on it, I have to restart PC in order to updates get done.

I am using a CFWheels inside a ColdFusion server. I have tried to use wheels reload inside box command line and change the environment to development.

Any idea of how to reload model methods without restart server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Go to CFadmin and look under *Server Settings > Caching* There's a checkbox *Trusted cache*. Uncheck this. There's also a button *Clear Template Cache Now*. Click this.

Comment: thank for the response, but still not working. May be CFWheels and not the CF server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I did anything with CFWheels, but `/?reload=true` is what I used in the past. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Also you will have to add the reloadPassword=yourPassword if you have set it in the config/settings.cfm.

Comment: thank you so much, due to cfwheels have been installed on a coldfusion local server. You have to use a specific route on a domain for passing the /?reload=true.